# Role Select Menu discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so, im making a sleect menu roles right, and i was wondering how would i make it so the followup text would all the role names that the person chose and not just 1 role name like how i added it to be

this is my code:

```
const samplemebed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor("Red")
                .setTitle("test")
                .setDescription(`Hi, this is a menu test`)
                const roleadded = new Array();
                const roleremoved = new Array();

            if (interaction.values == 'server') {
                const mashiro = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("1063076488594862130");
                if(interaction.member.roles.cache.has(mashiro.id)){
                    roleremoved.push(mashiro)
                    interaction.member.roles.remove(mashiro)
                    interaction.followUp({embeds:[samplemebed], ephemeral:true })
                  } else {
                    roleadded.push(mashiro)
                    interaction.member.roles.add(mashiro)
                    interaction.followUp({embeds:[samplemebed], ephemeral:true })
                  }
                await interaction.followUp({ embeds: [samplemebed], ephemeral: true })
            }
```